# mmenu - how to get the 'Drag open' Add-on on working with two menus?

Tags: swipe, mmenu

To open the mmenu on a swipe gesture, you can include hammer.js and configure the add-on in the options when initializing the menu (see http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/drag-open.html):

```
_JQ('#rightMenu').mmenu({        
    dragOpen: true
}, {
    // configuration
    clone: true
});

_JQ('#leftMenu').mmenu({        
    dragOpen: true
}, {
    // configuration
    clone: true
});
```

That works fine for one menu, but as I have two menus on one site (one opening from the left side, one from the right), the add-on does only work on the first (the left) menu, but not on the second (right) menu. How to get it work on both menus?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:
1. The menus have IDs like "left-menu" and "right-menu".
2. You have a couple of links on the page so that you can click on to open eatch menu.
3. The links IDs are "left-menu-link" and "right-menu-link".
4. The DIVs reagions where you will perform the "swiperight" or the "swipeleft" actions have a CSS class named "swipeble-area".
You could load jQueryMobile (eventualy with, only, the required funcs.) and use same script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.swipeble-area").on("swipeleft swiperight", function (e) {
        if ($("#left-menu").css("display") == "none" && $("#right-menu").css("display") == "none") {
            if (e.type === "swiperight") {
                $("#left-menu-link").click();
            } else if (e.type === "swipeleft") {
                $("#right-menu-link").click();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this is usefull.